# if statement in textbox error

Tags: c#, winforms

Doing a gui project for course and ran into a problem with my code. I have to run a bool method that will test to make sure that the words "tropical or saltwater" are only entered in and return true if correct.

But im having problems with  getting the if statement to match the string that i have given it in the expression.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private bool Fishtype()
    {
        if (txtFishType.Text == "Tropical" | "easy" )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool Fishsize()
    {
        if(txtFishSize >= 3 && txtFishSize <= 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Tropical" | "easy"` - what do you think this does? And where did you get that idea from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant for your if statement to be:

```
if (txtFishType.Text == "Tropical" || txtFishType.Text == "saltwater" ) { return true; }
```

Comment: The reason for this is that `||` is a logical OR operator whereas `|` is a bitwise OR operator.

Comment: Also just `return (txtFishType.Text == "Tropical" || txtFishType.Text == "saltwater" )` is shorter

Comment: Is "`saltwater`" the same as "`easy`"?

Comment: His question says, "will test to make sure that the words "tropical or saltwater" "